# how to download pictures with wget

Tags: batch-file, wget, curl

i would like to download pictures from http://myhomepage.com/plots/20150111-03/4711/4712.png every 3 hours. "20150111-03" is variable, rest is stable. That means every 3 hours the download looks like:

http:// myhomepage.com/plots/**20150111-01**/4711/4712.png --- 
http:// myhomepage.com/plots/**20150111-02**/4711/4712.png ---
http:// myhomepage.com/plots/**20150111-03**/4711/4712.png

how i can manage this with wget (curl) and .bat file in windows?

bye Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started

```
@echo off

:: Get current day month and year, padded with zeroes
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-3 usebackq" %%a in (`wmic path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year`) do (
    if not "%%c"=="" (
        set y=%%c
        set m=0%%b
        set d=0%%a
    )
)

set m=%m:~-2%
set d=%d:~-2%

:: Loop over image files, in this case, 100 of them
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /L %%i in (1,1,100) do (
    set index=0%%i
    set index=!index:~-2!
    set url=http://myhomepage.com/plots/!y!!m!!d!-!index!/4711/4712.png
    wget -O "!y!!m!!d!-!index!.png" "!url!"
) 

endlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

Comment: thank you very much: this works! what i have to do if the time stamps are not every hour or 100 times but in this way: 20150109-00 20150109-03 20150109-06 20150109-09 20150109-12 20150109-15 20150109-18 20150109-21

and for the next 3 days?

bye

Comment: In that case you should type 'help for', and see that you can set a step value in the for loop, e.g. 'for /L %%i in (1,3,100)'. Doing the next three days is harder: you could loop over current day, +1, +2, but you'd also need logic to go into a new month or year.